# Proper punctuation of cases in statement of Lemma

Tags: article-writing

I found a very similar question asked on the TeX StackExchange [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499/proper-punctuation-after-cases-environment) but the answer was not as definitive as I hoped for.

My question is in regard to how one properly punctuates the following Lemma.  Should a comma be used at the end of each case? If not, what would be the proper way to punctuate the cases environments?

**Lemma 6.** *Under the specified parameters constraints in Definition 3*
\begin{array}{*3{>{\displaystyle}l}}
&\lim_{z\to 0}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
&=%
\begin{cases}
(\omega+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu<0,\\
(\omega)^{(n)}, &\nu>0,
\end{cases}\\[1em]
&\lim_{z\to\infty}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
&=%
\begin{cases}
(\omega-1)^{(n)}, &\nu<0,\\
(\omega-1+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu>0.
\end{cases}
\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not really any hard rules for these situations that I am aware of, but I would pick either

> **Option One:**\begin{array}{*3{>{\displaystyle}l}}
> &\lim_{z\to 0}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
> &=%
> \begin{cases}
> (\omega+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu<0\\
> (\omega)^{(n)}, &\nu>0,
> \end{cases}\\[1em]
> &\lim_{z\to\infty}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
> &=%
> \begin{cases}
> (\omega-1)^{(n)}, &\nu<0\\
> (\omega-1+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu>0.
> \end{cases}
> \end{array}

or

> **Option Two:**\begin{array}{*3{>{\displaystyle}l}}
> &\lim_{z\to 0}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
> &=%
> \begin{cases}
> (\omega+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu<0\\
> (\omega)^{(n)}, &\nu>0
> \end{cases}\\[1em]
> &\lim_{z\to\infty}\tilde g_{n,\omega}(z,\nu)%
> &=%
> \begin{cases}
> (\omega-1)^{(n)}, &\nu<0\\
> (\omega-1+\nu)^{(n)}, &\nu>0.
> \end{cases}
> \end{array}

If you are using commas instead of, for example, writing $$(\omega-1)^{(n)} \ \text{ for }\ \nu<0$$ then you definitely *do* want the first set of commas and you definitely *don't* want commas after *every* inequality, but you should have the period at the end, and it's a matter of taste whether the comma at the end of the first limit is necessary.

Comment: I was beginning to lean towards option one as I was writing the question and will go with that.  Thank you.